# Use of caption package resulting in text "figure" in margin

Tags: captions

I am writing a two column paper. After adding the `caption` package to my tex file, the text "figure" now appears in the left margin for every standalone figure as is shown in the picture.

[image: latex doc pic]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{phdsymp} %!PN

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{caption}



\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,margin=3cm}

\includegraphics[scale=.30]{example-image-a}

\caption{A caption with long text bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is caused by some interaction between the `caption` package and my `phdsymp` class file(see [cls](https://github.com/jaspervdj/thesis/blob/master/doc/phdsymp.cls),[bst](https://github.com/jaspervdj/thesis/blob/master/doc/phdsymp.bst)) since it does not
happen without using the class file. I need the `caption` package for proper
aligning of text underneath figures but I do not want "figure" appearing in
the margin. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Simply put: `caption` is not compatible with the class.

Comment: Is this a class file of your own creation, or is someone else suggesting that you use this class file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `caption` package is not compatible with the class, which redefines the caption format to its liking.

You can somewhat emulate the same effect as with `margin=3cm` by using a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{phdsymp} %!PN
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering

\includegraphics[scale=.30]{example-image-a}

\parbox{\dimexpr\columnwidth-6cm}{
  \caption{A caption with long text bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Don't use the obsolete package `times`. If you want Times, add

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

instead.

[image]

However, I don't see a real reason for using a different format for the caption than the provided one.

[image]

Comment: The former caption format looks good for figures in a column but I have some figures that are nearly full page width and the caption looked terrible for those. Now it's looking just like I want, thanks!